# Splitting an Angular D3 Donut in to 2 sections

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js, angular-directive

I am using Angular and D3 to display a donut graph, see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Eoa2zAAEmTcnNfRNjgE4?p=preview

From the above, you can see in the directive mark up i am passing a parameter for how much the donut should be filled: percent="80"

How can i modify this to show something like, of the 80%, 20% is pending in say a different colour or pattern?

E.g:

```
<my-directive radius="250" percent="80" pending="20" text="hello"></my-directive>

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            radius: '=',
            percent: '=',
            text: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var radius = scope.radius,
                percent = scope.percent,
                percentLabel = scope.text,
                format = d3.format(".0%"),
                progress = 0;

            var svg = d3.select(element[0])
                .append('svg')
                .style('width', radius/2+'px')
                .style('height', radius/2+'px');

            var donutScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, 100])
                .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

            var color = "red";

            var data = [
                [0,100,"#b8b5b8"],
                [0,0,color]
            ];

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(radius/6)
                .outerRadius(radius/4)
                .startAngle(function(d){return donutScale(d[0]);})
                .endAngle(function(d){return donutScale(d[1]);});

            var text = svg.append("text")
                .attr("x",radius/4)
                .attr("y",radius/4)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size","14px")
                .style("fill","white")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(percentLabel);

            var path = svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .style("fill", function(d){return d[2];})
                .attr("d", arc)
                .each(function(d) {
                    this._current = d;
                    // console.log(this._current)
                });

            // update the data!
            data = [
                [0,100,"#b8b5b8"],
                [0,percent,color]
            ];

            path
                .data(data)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+radius/4+","+radius/4+")")
                .transition(200).duration(2150).ease('linear')
                .attrTween("d", function (a) {
                    var i  = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
                    var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent)
                    this._current = i(0);
                    // console.log(this._current);
                    return function(t) {
                        text.text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
                        return arc(i(t));
                    };
                });
        }
    };
});
```